# Cant get polygons to display in primefaces

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces, polygon

Ok so i am using primefaces gmap in order to display multiple polygons that are retrieved from a database, however i cant get it to display on the page, i know the coordinates are being passed in correctly and my code code is similar to the showcase on primefaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/polygons.xhtml
So basically i am stumped.
Here is my backing bean code

```
 @PostConstruct
public void init() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        DBConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demeter2.0", "root", "root");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Animal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Animal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {

        if (DBConn != null) {

            String sql = "SELECT ST_AsText(markers) FROM paddock WHERE idPaddock > 0";
            ps = (PreparedStatement) DBConn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            polygonModel = new DefaultMapModel();
            if (!rs.next()) {

                //return null;
            } else {

                rs.beforeFirst();
                Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
                while (rs.next()) {

                    String value = rs.getString(1);
                    String valuereal = value.replaceAll("[^0-9 .,]+", "");
                    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(valuereal.split(",")));
                    myList.remove(myList.size() - 1);
                    for (String coordString : myList) {

                        String[] parts = coordString.split(" ");

                        String latS = parts[0];
                        String lngS = parts[1];

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(latS);
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngS);

                        LatLng coord = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        polygon.getPaths().add(coord);
                        System.out.println(coord);

                    }
                    polygon.setStrokeColor("#FF9900");
                    polygon.setFillColor("#FF9900");
                    polygon.setStrokeOpacity(0.7);
                    polygon.setFillOpacity(0.7);
                    polygonModel.addOverlay(polygon);

                }//end while

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {

            ps.close();
            DBConn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And the JSF code

```
  <h:form prependId="false">    
                    <p:growl id="growl" life="3000" showDetail="true" />

                    <p:gmap id="gmap" center="36.890257,30.707417" zoom="13" type="HYBRID" style="width:100%;height:400px" model="#{paddock.polygonModel}">
                        <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{paddock.onPolygonSelect}" update="growl" />
                    </p:gmap>
                </h:form>
```

Comment: Similar != identical... https://www.google.nl/search?q=similar+vs+identical find the differences and see if it influences things. Get it to work without a database first... Most likely that won't work either. Or your coordinates are on a completely different part of the world... or...

Comment: From what i can see using system.out and tomcat the coordinates are coming through its just not creating the polygon and adding it to the overlay.